# Searching through multidimensional array to get information?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a multidimensional array that shows information from RiotGames's (the creators of League of Legends) API.
The request to their API searched with a username and summonerID (playerID) returns information
that looks like this :

```
Array ( [summonerId] => 34943406 [playerStatSummaries] => 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [playerStatSummaryType] => AramUnranked5x5 [wins] => 273 [modifyDate] => 1416009440000 [aggregatedStats] => Array ( [totalChampionKills] => 5808 [totalTurretsKilled] => 298 [totalAssists] => 9025 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [playerStatSummaryType] => Ascension [wins] => 2 [modifyDate] => 1415466770000 [aggregatedStats] => Array ( ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [playerStatSummaryType] => CAP5x5 [wins] => 41 [modifyDate] => 1416177610000 [aggregatedStats] => Array ( [totalChampionKills] => 562 [totalMinionKills] => 9087 [totalTurretsKilled] => 79 [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 2371 [totalAssists] => 475 ) )
```

and it goes on, depending on how many gamemodes the player has played. Every gamemode starts with a number [1/2/3], but is not the same for every user, depending on which gamemodes they have played.

My question is how do I search through the array to find "Cap5x5" for example and take out just those stats to display them in a clean-looking table with stats. The problem is that for my account, the gamemode "RankedSolo5x5" is on [9] but for a friend's account it is on [7]. This is a very vague question but it is kinda hard to explain.

Comment: will CAP5x5 always be in the key `playerStatSummaryType`? it's very important...

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean by "key", the thing before the "wins" is the name of the gamemode , so the name is static, but sometimes it won't be in [2] but maybe in [3] so it would be
 
[3] => Array ( [playerStatSummaryType] => CAP5x5 ...
and so on

Comment: take a look at my answer... I have also generated the table ONLY IF the playerStatSumarryType is CAP5x5 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `CAP5x5`  is found only in `playerStatSummaryType`

```
<?php
//(...)some code you might have before this table...

function returnTable($array, $searchFor) {
  $content = '<table>';
  foreach($array['playerStatSummaries'] as $playerStat) {
     if($playerStat['playerStatSummaryType'] == $searchFor) {
         $content .= '<tr>';
             $content .= '<td>wins</td><td>' . $playerStat['wins'] . '</td>';
             $content .= '<td>totalChampionKills</td><td>' . $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalChampionKills'] . '</td>';
             $content .= '<td>totalMinionKills</td><td>' . $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalMinionKills'] . '</td>';
             $content .= '<td>totalTurretsKilled</td><td>' . $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalTurretsKilled'] . '</td>';
             $content .= '<td>totalNeutralMinionsKilled</td><td>' . $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalNeutralMinionsKilled'] . '</td>';
             $content .= '<td>totalAssists</td><td>' . $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalAssists'] . '</td>';

         $content .= '</tr>';
     } else {
         echo 'ERROR: Stats not found for this game mode. Try a different one';
         continue;
     }
  }

  $content .= '</table>';

  return $content;
}

echo returnTable($array, 'CAP5x5');
//OR...
echo returnTable($array, 'WhatEverGameYouWant');
//OR...
echo returnTable($array, $gamemode); //if $gamemode = 'CAP5x5' (for example...)
```

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: this is great but for some reason it's returning only the wins, but  not the rest -  ( " wins 41 totalChampionKills  totalMinionKills  totalTurretsKilled  totalNeutralMinionsKilled  totalAssists  totalChampionKills  totalMinionKills  totalTurretsKilled  totalNeutralMinionsKilled  totalAssists  totalChampionKills  totalMinionKills  totalTurretsKilled  totalNeutralMinionsKilled  totalAssists  totalChampionKills  totalMinionKills  totalTurretsKilled  totalNeutralMinionsKilled  totalAssists  totalChampionKills  totalMinionKills  totalTurretsKilled  totalNeutralMinionsKilled  totalAssists"

Comment: It is showing the [totalChampionKills] without the [] instead of the values that are showed in them

Comment: but if I write " echo $playerStat['aggregatedStats']['totalChampionKills'] " before the foreach loop there is no problem showing the actual "total champion kills" number

Comment: yes, it's perfect. Thanks for the help :) @Ares Draguna

Comment: what do I add to the code if I user doesn't have stats for the chosen gamemode? eg. user hasn't played CAP5x5

Comment: works well but I want it to give an error message like "Stats not found for the chosen usre/gamemode".
Also for the CAP5x5 I have a variable called "$gamemode" that comes from a form dropdown menu

Comment: ;) check it now ... and for the rest, please try to solve it yourself... otherwise you will NOT learn anything...

Answer (score 1):

assuming that there is always only one item like CAP5x5 in stat summaries array:

```
function search($search_term){
    foreach ($result['playerStatSummaries'] as $statsItem){
        if($statsItem['playerStatSummaryType'] == $search_term) return $statsItem
    }
    return false;
}

$myStats = search('CAP5x5');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = get_riotgames_array(); // pseudocall 

array_filter($arr, function($elem) { // will filter by checking type
  return array_reduce($elem['playerStatSummaries'], function($memo, $el) {
    // whether type is OK, carry true
    return $memo = $memo || $el['playerStatSummaryType'] === 'CAP5x5'
  }, false)
});
```

Hope it hepls.